# I want to install a free oracle database on my Windows machine and I want to get practice on Toad for Oracle. What are my options?

Tags: database, oracle, toad

My intention is to become familiar with Toad for Oracle. For this, I would like to be able to connect to an Oracle database, preferably locally on my machine. Can someone please give me directions on what I need to download/minimum requirements for my machine, etc.?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a Free version of Oracle, I suggest you choose Oracle Express from the following link

[Oracle Database 11g Express Edition](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/database-technologies/express-edition/overview/index.html)

> Free to develop, deploy, and distribute
>
> Oracle Database 11g Express Edition (Oracle Database XE) is an
>   entry-level, small-footprint database based on the Oracle Database 11g
>   Release 2 code base.  It's free to develop, deploy, and distribute;
>   fast to download; and simple to administer.
>
> Oracle Database XE is a great starter database for:
>
> - Developers working on Node.js, Python, PHP, Java, .NET, XML, and Open    Source applications
> - DBAs who need a free, starter database for training and deployment
> - Independent Software Vendors (ISVs) and hardware vendors who want a starter database to distribute free of charge
> - Educational institutions and students who need a free database for their curriculum

About system requirements, you will find detail information at [this Oracle's documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17781_01/install.112/e18803/toc.htm#XEINW102)

Hope this helps!

Comment: There appears to be this idea floating around that once you install an Oracle database on your system, you've effectively made your machine slower, and you never truly get rid of it, even after an uninstall. What does this mean?

Comment: I think you can try tuning your PC, for example, cleaning, defagment...